# PHP file upload not working on CentOS6 but working on Apache2 on OSX 10.8

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have two simple scripts to upload a file from a particular path on a local machine and place it on an Apache server.  It's working fine on Apache built into OSX 10.8 but not on CentOS 6.
Here is the code:

```
http://mysite.mydomain.com/logsend.php?logfilename=logfile.log
```

Which then goes to "logsend.php":

```
<?php
$logfilename = $_GET['logfilename'];
$target_url = 'http://mysite.mydomain.com/logaccept.php';
$localdir = '/usr/local/mysoftware/logs/';
$logurl = $localdir . $logfilename;
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$logurl);
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

This then goes to logaccept.php:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = realpath('uploads/') . '/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file_contents']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_contents']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Log file successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
?>
```

The mac returns "Log file successfully uploaded" in the browser window as expected, but on the CentOS box I just get the PHP white screen of nothingness.  Nothing shows up as an error in the Apache error_log and I'm stuck as to how to further troubleshoot this.

Any ideas?  I attempted to load some debug code into the PHP files, but I still only get white space back:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: In all probability, this is an env problem. Check permissions and paths.And if they look ok, check them again, and still if there are no issues...well check again

Comment: Thanks.  It's strange as I can add lines that echo all of the environments fine in the first script, but it's as though it doesn't make it to logaccept.php somehow..  Even if I put an echo "hello world"; at the top of logaccept.php it doesn't show up..   If I go directly to log accept.php then it does.

Comment: I think it's the curl bit that's failing, though that's beyond my PHP knowledge.  I notice PHP was compiled with --without-curl  although further dow the .ini file it says curl is enabled.  This --without-curl doesn't exist on the OSX compile command.

Comment: you should get an undefined function error, if curl was not there..

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar problem on a centOs machine.  It turned out to be the selinux which is turned on by default in centOs.  Make sure you have write permissions, and disable selinux.  (or configure it to give your apache user access)

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: It's disabled, but thanks for the suggestion.  I've had problems due to that before!

Comment: I spent two days tracking that down a few weeks ago.  I was hoping it was something that simple.